# Kendo UI Grid Excel Export not working with ClientGroupFooterTemplate that references a Kendo value

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo MVC grid with columns defined as follows:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.PoolId).Title("Pool").Hidden(true);

columns.Bound(p => p.Client).Title("Client").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width:120px;" })
    .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("<div>#:value# Totals:</div>");
```

With a group on the "PoolId" field:

```
...
.Group(group => group.Add(g => g.PoolId))
...
```

Excel export works when I don't reference **any** Kendo values in the ClientGroupFooterTemplate (or don't include the footer template at all) but just silently fails (doesn't generate a file) when I try to reference any Kendo value using '#='

For example, the following **works** and allows exports:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Client).Title("Client").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width:120px;" })
    .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("<div>Totals:</div>");
```

but the following is an example of a footer that causes exports to **fail**:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Client).Title("Client").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width:120px;" })
    .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("<div>#= kendo.format('{0:C}', aggregates.PoolContributions.min) #</div>");
```

I'm using Kendo UI MVC version 2021.2.511.545

How do I get the Excel export working with ClientGroupFooterTemplate?

NOTE: I see the following error in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined
    at Object.eval [as groupFooterTemplate] (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:234), <anonymous>:3:82)
    at kendo.all.js:15113
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at init._footer (kendo.all.js:15107)
    at init._dataRow (kendo.all.js:14952)
    at init._dataRows (kendo.all.js:15005)
    at init._rows (kendo.all.js:15245)
    at init.workbook (kendo.all.js:14865)
    at init.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:15382)
    at Object.d (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key item I realized is that the data models are different between the Excel export and on-screen. What I ended up using was a footer like the following:

```
.ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#if (data !== undefined && data.group !== undefined) {##:group.value# Totals:# } else if (data !== undefined) {##:value# Totals:# }#")
```

*value* was accessible when rendering on-screen but I had to use *group.value* during Excel exports.